# Bloomberg Professional Hogging The Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, bloomberg

We have a WPF application that uses controls e.g. Grid, Trees, Tabs etc.  One issue that we are facing is that when the application is running in  maximized mode, having some other high frequency application (e.g. Bloomberg Professional Dashboard) running on the same monitor in the background, the controls on our application don't refresh every time. For example, if we expand the tree nodes, the child nodes don't appear. If we press "Select + A" to select everything in the grid, nothing gets selected unless we then click on the screen or move mouse. If we click on the tabs they don't switch too. Seems like as if our windows messages get stuck due to some reason.

However, if a user presses the Restore button to come out of the maximize mode, everything works as it should. Also, if they keep our application in maximized mode on a separate screen than the one where they have their Bloomberg dashboard opened everything works fine as well.

Seems like Bloomberg application may be takes priority on the screen it runs.

Has anyone come across such issue and any ideas how to resolve this?